# Tensorflow and protobuf version problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Keras which uses Tensorflow (GPU) which uses protobuf using python 3.6 on Windows 10. The version of Tensorflow is 2.1.0 and it came with protobuf 3.11. However, should I try to import Tensorflow, it raises the following error:

> from google.protobuf.pyext import _message (...) ImportError: DLL load failed: (...)

which from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046 I understand that it's tensorflow using a file no longer present in protobuf >3.6.0

However, downgrading to protobuf 3.6.0 raises another error during the creation of an Embedding Layer with Keras:

> AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'append'

Further downgrading of protobuf still causes other errors. Could it be tensorflow and Keras needing different versions of protobuf? Can I even have 2 separate versions for them in the same virtual environment (i'm using PyCharm)?

So which version of protobuf does tensorflow 2.1.0 (and Keras 2.3.1) freaking need? Can I solve it by using another combination of versions (older tensorflow and/or Keras) and if so which?

Comment: As a workaround, try to install latest version of `TF 2.4`, most of `protobuf` issues were resolved. From TF 2.3 onwards keras are integrated with Tensorflow, you can use `tf.keras`. If you are still facing issues after upgrade please let us know, we will help you.Thanks!

Comment: I ended up settling for version 1. something where everything worked but I AM NEVER USING PIP FOR DATA SCIENCE AGAIN. Ever since then I have used miniconda and had no major problems. It even downloaded necessary GPU drivers for pytorch by itself.